# Python Rolling Window with Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a hard time looping through my pandas data frame while trying to apply a) a specific window size (6hours) and b) specific step size (1hour). I have tried the pd.rolling function but it doesn't return any values and also doesn't allow me to incorporate a step size.

Below is an example of my dataframe (the entire data set is from 9-01-2018 to 9-30-2018):

```
195 2018-09-01 02:05:00  19.129037 -25.480032

198 2018-09-01 02:10:00  19.858348 -25.480032

201 2018-09-01 02:15:00  20.485054 -25.580032

204 2018-09-01 02:20:00  13.310732 -25.880032

207 2018-09-01 02:25:00  12.994463 -26.180032
```

Comment: So you want to down-sample the resolution to 1 hour and a 6-hour moving average?

Comment: pseudo code:

take all values within a 6 hour window -> do something
then
move to the next hour (in this case it would be 2018-09-01 3:05:00)
take all values within the next 6 hour window -> do something
etc...

Comment: in principle it would be like the following, but I'm not sure how to work with the date time column as an index I guess:

for i in range(0, len(df), 1hour):
    for j in range(i,i+6hours,1):
        print(j)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by step size of one hour? How different is it from the window? 6hours window means that you'd read the rows one by one and keep those rows whose time stamps were within 6 hours of the current row. How about step size? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: Hi Iqigai
I've got it sorted so far:

for i in pd.date_range(start=start_obs_time, end=end_obs_time, freq=str(moving_step) + "S"):
do something

Comment: If the problem is solved, post an answer. Don't add "(solved)" to the title.

Comment: @mzjn kk, thank you

Comment: Why not use rolling with a window of 6.  Resample your data to second frequency and forward fill then add a rolling window for every six seconds

Comment: You can alsoi directly use time window by first converting the Time Stamps column to datetime format using the `pd.to_datetime`. Then you can directly use a window of exactly 6hours without having to resample.